# Git: Pull changes from one file into another specific file

Tags: git

If on the master branch I have a file in the path path/to/foo and I want to pull the changes from the file path/to/foo into another file with the path differentpath/to/bar, is there a way to do this? Essentially, I want the file bar to track changes from the file foo.

Comment: "pull the changes" may be misleading, "git pull" probably won't help here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+apply+changes+file